Defining length for fft in Matlab
I have a question to the command fft in Matlab. By using the default settings Matlab assumes the signal to be periodic with a periodicity of 2π. However, for my problem I need to apply the FFT to a signal that is periodic in L ≠ 2π.
I am sure there is a proper function for this in Matlab. I am pretty new in Matlab and I didn't find anything in the documentation of fft.
To be precise: I want fast fourier transform an array with N emenets by using the frequencies [0, L/N,..., L*(N-1)/N]. I know that it would be easy to write a code by simply calculating the fft manually, but I guess there must be an efficient command available in matlab.

The FFT is an algorithm that computes a DFT, not a continuous-domain FT. The periodicity is N, the length of the signal. In a discrete world it makes no sense to have a periodicity of 2π, since that is not an integer number.

But when I look at the documentation of fft (https://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fft.html), it looks like we use frequencies in the range [0, 2pi/N,..., 2Pi*(N-1)/N]. My question is, can one use the frequencies [0, L/N,..., L*(N-1)/N]?

Some people want to think of the (radial) frequencies being in the range -π/2 to π/2 even. That depends on interpretation. But the actual algorithm uses frequencies k=0..N-1, given samples at n=0..N-1. If you explain a bit more what you really want to accomplish, we might be able to help you. Right now I’m not certain about what you need.

I added a sentence in my question, but is it true that the algorithm uses frequencies k=0...N-1? From the definition it looks like [0, 2pi/N,..., 2Pi*(N-1)/N].

This is what the FFT computes: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform#Definition — it uses k=0..N-1 as frequencies. But you can assign frequencies however you want, it’s just about how you interpret the maths. Note how the DFT does not consider a sampling frequency, it just has N input samples and produces N output frequencies. There is no specific values associated to the X axis (sample locations) of either input or output.

You might want to ask about your specific use case over at [dsp.se], since you have a question about how to interpret the output of the FFT. It is not a question about programming (what this site is about).
